# The equality of successors of two natural numbers implies the equality of the numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $x,y$ are two natural numbers defined as the smallest inductive set (containing $0$). Assuming only the axioms of extensionality, pairing, separation, union, and infinity I want to prove that $x^+=y^+\implies x=y$, where by definition $x^+= x\cup \{x\}$.

I think that this problem would be easily solved using the induction principle which may be deduced from the above-mentioned axioms. However, is there any direct proof?

My attempt was as follows. If $x\not =y$, then $x\in y\in x$. But I can’t find a contradiction in this observation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it necessary to use the axiom of Regularity to prove the successor function being injective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590121/is-it-necessary-to-use-the-axiom-of-regularity-to-prove-the-successor-function-b)

Comment: No, I wanted to follow the line of my reasoning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transitive set is a set $S$ such that for all $z, y$ such that $z \in y \in S$, we have $z \in S$.

We now prove the following theorem by induction:

> For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n$ is a transitive set.

We now prove the following by induction:

> For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \notin n$.

You will need transitivity for the inductive hypothesis.

Now suppose $n^+ = k^+$. Then $k \in k^+ = n^+$, so either $k \in n$ or $k = n$. If $k = n$, we are done. If $k \in n$, then consider that $n \in n^+ = k^+$, so either $n = k$ or $n \in k$. If $n = k$, we are done. If $n \in k$, then we have $n \in k \in n$, and thus $n \in n$ by transitivity. But we just showed that $n \notin n$; contradiction.

Comment: This proof uses the induction principle which I tried not to use. But I just realize that any proof must use it because the problem has allowed the use of the infinity principle which implies the induction principle

Comment: @Philomath The induction principle is practically the definition of $\mathbb{N}$, so I don’t see how we can avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

$x\in x$ is a contradiction because every ordinal $\alpha$ verifies that $\alpha\not \in \alpha$, and every natural number is an ordinal (the finite ones)

Comment: This problem doesn’t assume knowledge of ordinal numbers but thanks for including this nice proof